# Pulling all file names from a SharePoint site and it's subsites

Tags: 2013

So I was tasked with trying to gather all the filenames from our SharePoint site and it's respective subsites. After researching for a while I learned that using PowerShell would probably be the best way about this. However, I do not have the required permissions. I do not have administrator access on our windows server.

So is there another way of completing this task that anyone can think of? And how would I approach that? Thank you so much!

Comment: did you try using PowerShell and CSOM???